# Using render field for select option in django

Tags: python, django

I am using `widget_tweaks` in my django project. For an input tag, I am using it like :

```
{% render_field form.enrollment_no class='form-control' id='id_enrollment_number' placeholder='Enrollment Number' type='text' %}
```

Now, I want to achieve something similar for `<select>` tag:

```
           <select class='form-control' id='id_faculty'>

            {% for faculties in faculty %}
            <option value="{{ faculties }}">{{ faculties }}</option>

            {% endfor %}

          </select>
```

But, I think I am doing something wrong, because it would not help while checking the validity on form submit. Please help me to solve this.

Edit 1:
Also, I am getting faculty from a different model:

```
form = StudentForm()

    faculty = Faculty.objects.all()


    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form' : form,'faculty' : faculty}).
```

Studen Model :

```
class Student(models.Model):
    """here goes model for users"""

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    enrollment_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Faculty Name:

```
class Faculty(models.Model):

    faculty_name = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.faculty_name
```

Student Form class:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

Other tables:

```
class Faculty(models.Model):

    faculty_name = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.faculty_name

class Department(models.Model):
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department_name = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.department_name


class Course(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_name = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name
```

Comment: Why not do `{% render_field form.MY_CHOICE_FIELD class='form-control' id='id_faculty'' %}` ?

Comment: Can you provide me some documentation for the same? I searched a lot but couldn't find anything similar. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Please post your Student model class and StudentForm class code.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir Have a look on my code.

Comment: In your template, it looks like you want to save a faculty against a student. But none of the Student and Faculty Models and Student Form suggest that you are saving faculty against Student. Do you have a foreign key to Faculty in you Student Model? If not then where will you save selected faculty from your template?

Comment: the thing is I have three tables, faculty, department & course. Department uses faculty as foreign key, course uses both department and student. Am I missing something here? I think I messed up things while database design. Please help me.